# jetty osgi : securing all servlet with one securityHandler

Tags: jetty, osgi, security, pax-web

I'm using jetty as an osgi bundle with paxweb.
I would like to be sure that all the servlets and resources registered thanks to the OSGI HttpService are secured by one common SecurityHandler (moreover I would like to use the JAASLoginService).
I also want to redirect all unauthenticated requests to a single login page.

Is it possible to configure this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

If all Servlets use the same HttpContext it's possible. 
As a runtime-container with a working Jaas I suggest using [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/). 
It provides all that is needed, including Pax Web as HTTPService including the HttpWhiteboard Extender.

Comment: How to force the usage of the same HttpContext by all Servlets?

Comment: well, one way could be by using the same HttpContext when using the whiteboard extender of pax-web for example [Pax-Web](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxweb/Pax+Web).

Comment: it doesn't avoid someone to directly register a servlet by using httpservice.registerservlet

Comment: no, this is a user and not a container or framework requirement, therefore it is up to the user who is in charge to design the application in a way that one HttpContext is used.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Apache Felix whiteboard HTTP support. You can just register filters in the registry and they are used by the underlying Jetty: http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-http-service.html

Filter service properties that are supported for filters:

```
pattern - Regular expression pattern to register filter with.
contextId - Id of context to register with.
service.ranking - Where in the chain this filter should be placed.
init.* - Filter initialization values.
```

I have not tried this myself yet but will soon ...

Comment: That would be the alternate aproach using felix instead of pax-web, since we have enough tools to choose it's up to the user which one fits him best :D. And I tried pax-web (of course) ;)